# ASP.NET Inject Identity

Tags: asp.net, .net, ninject

I am trying to inject UserManager and UserManager with Ninject. But it gives an error.

What is wrong with the binding?

UserStore

```
public class UserStoreModule : NinjectModule
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The load.
    /// </summary>
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IUserStore<Account>>()
            .To<UserStore<Account>>()
            .InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument("context", context => Kernel.Get<RovinMediaContext>());
    }
}
```

UserManager

```
public class UserManagerModule : NinjectModule
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The load.
    /// </summary>
    public override void Load()
    {
        Kernel.Bind<UserManager<Account>>().ToSelf();
    }
}
```

Result to the following error

Error activating string No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.

Activation path:
 2) Injection of dependency string into parameter connectionString of constructor of type RovinMediaContext

1) Request for MyDbContext